# How to convert a 4d Array of Strings in to a 4d Map of Strings

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to convert a 4D array of strings to Map of Maps of Maps of Maps of strings. If I am using `asMap()` function to a 4D array like this: `List<dynamic> tList = List.generate(1, (index) => List.generate(12, (m) => List.generate(31, (d) => List.generate(40, (i) => ""))));`  I will get a Map with a 3D array in it, like `{0: [[["", "", "",]["", "", "",]["", "", "",]]]etc.}`. What should I do to get something like `{0: 0: 0: 0: "", "", "", "", etc.}`

Answer (score 2):

Well `{0: 0: 0: 0: "", "", "", "", etc.}` isn't a valid map structure, so I'm going to assume you mean `{0: {0: {0: {0: "", 1: "", 2: "", 3: ""}}}}`.

One approach would be to loop over the lists, and generate your nested map structure using [collection for](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#collection-operators):

```dart
Map<int, Map<int, Map<int, Map<int, String>>>> tMap = {
  for (int a = 0; a < tList.length; a++)
    a: {
      for (int b = 0; b < tList[a].length; b++)
        b: {
          for (int c = 0; c < tList[a][b].length; c++)
            c: {
              for (int d = 0; d < tList[a][b][c].length; d++)
                d: tList[a][b][c][d],
            },
        },
    },
};
```

You could even define this functionality as an extension method like so:

```dart
extension List4dExtension<T> on List<List<List<List<T>>>> {
  Map<int, Map<int, Map<int, Map<int, T>>>> as4dMap() {
    return {
      for (int a = 0; a < length; a++)
        a: {
          for (int b = 0; b < this[a].length; b++)
            b: {
              for (int c = 0; c < this[a][b].length; c++)
                c: {
                  for (int d = 0; d < this[a][b][c].length; d++)
                    d: this[a][b][c][d],
                },
            },
        },
    };
  }
}
```

And then you would be able call `.as4dMap()` on your `tList` variable.

```dart
print(tList.as4dMap());
```

That said, you will also need to update the type of your variable from `List<dynamic>` to `List<List<List<List<String>>>>` in order to use the extension. (you can also omit the type and declare the variable as a `var` or `final` and let type inference do the rest).

Or, if it makes things easier, you can use typedef to have more concise types:

```dart
typedef List4d<T> = List<List<List<List<T>>>>;
typedef Map4d<A, B> = Map<A, Map<A, Map<A, Map<A, B>>>>;
```

And then you can use the shortened typdef types instead of the full types:

```dart
List4d<String> tList = ...
```